# Installing pip3 mysqlclient results in error

Tags: python-3, raspbian-buster, pip

I have tried a few different ways to get this installed.  mysqlclient and also tried pip install MySQL-python both result in error.

```
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ pip install MySQL-python
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-YvczBg/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-YvczBg/MySQL-python/
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ pip install MySQLclient
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting MySQLclient
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/97/7326248ac8d5049968bf4ec708a5d3d4806e412a42e74160d7f266a3e03a/mysqlclient-1.4.6.tar.gz (85kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 1.3MB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    sh: 1: mariadb_config: not found
    sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-n01LjQ/MySQLclient/setup.py", line 16, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 61, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 29, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (_mysql_config_path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-n01LjQ/MySQLclient/
pi@raspberrypi:/ $
```

Is something wrong with my install on rasbian buster?

This worked last week for 10 other Pis i have.  But this week I cannot get anything to install.  I tested my pip3 to see if it was a bad pip install but that works for other installs.  for whatever reason I cannot get mysqlclients to install.  Any ideas?

What I have tried

1. I have uninstalled and reinstalled python 1,2,3
2. I have reinstalled Buster I have pulled my hair out! lol
3. I have also used pip3 install mysqlclient and same results.
4. I have used sudo pip3 install but same results

I have also tried installing from rasbian repository

```
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ sudo apt-get install mysqlclient
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysqlclient
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ sudo apt-get install MySQL-python
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package MySQL-python
```

Comment: Why are you not installing from the Raspbian repository with apt install?

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:/ $ sudo apt-get install mysqlclient
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysqlclient

Comment: it is not available via the rasbian repository

Comment: The non-python MySQL stuff has been replaced with mariaSQL.

Answer (score 1):

After rethinking how this works I was able to install mysqldb with the following command.

```
 sudo apt-get install python3-mysqldb
```

This works for my above script.

Comment: For future reference `apt search mysql | grep python` might have saved you time guessing at package names here.

Comment: Another way to find packages on the repository: `apt list 'python*mysql*'`.

Comment: Mark it as the best answer if it works, please.